# plot dots on multiple lines in line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot small circles on lines to represent data points in a line chart, using the following code:

```
// Add the scatterplot
  g.selectAll("dot")
    .data(newdata[0].values)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })            
    //.attr("stroke", "blue")
    //.attr("stroke-width", 2)
    //.attr("fill", "none")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
      div.html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>" + d.value)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });
```

But the problem is, I can only pass one element's values at a time: `.data(newdata[0]).values)`. This will only plot dots on one line. I can put the whole code in loop and use counter `i` instead of 0. But that will be a very bad solution. Below is my data-structure:

```
[{
  "id": "primary",
  "values": [{
    "date": "2011-03-31T18:30:00.000Z",
    "value": 58.13
  }, {
    "date": "2011-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",
    "value": 53.98
  }]
}, {
  "id": "secondary",
  "values": [{
    "date": "2011-03-31T18:30:00.000Z",
    "value": 28.13
  }, {
    "date": "2011-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",
    "value": 35.13
  }]
}];
```

[Here is the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/opajad48/)

Please suggest what to do! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about flattening your data first by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var values = newdata.reduce(function(arr, d){
     return arr.concat(d.values);
}, []);
```

This will give you an array of all the objects you need to construct your points:

```
[{"date":"2011-03-31T18:30:00.000Z","value":58.13},
 {"date":"2011-04-30T18:30:00.000Z","value":53.98},
 {"date":"2011-03-31T18:30:00.000Z","value":28.13},
 {"date":"2011-04-30T18:30:00.000Z","value":35.13}]
```

Then of course just bind these values to create all your circles:

```
g.selectAll("dot")
 .data(values)
 ... // etc
```